# Measure of intermittency/continuousness of a signal

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, signal-processing, intermittent-time-series

I have three signals (below) each having the same standard deviation, however, are clearly very different temporally.

[image]

Is there some such metric that could be calculated for each of these signals to give an indication of how they vary over time, such as a measure of continuousness or intermittency if such a metric exists.

If possible, I would like to do this by calculating a single number for each of these signals, rather than windowing into smaller chunks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting each of your signals to the frequency domain using a frequency domain transform such as the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) will allow you to distinguish between the three signals shown above as follows:

- 1st plot is a step function and will show (relatively) high frequency components centred around one peak
- 2nd plot will show frequency components centred around a (relatively) low frequency peak and will be easily distinguished from the first plot
- 3rd plot will show multiple peaks in the frequency and could be distinguished by counting the number of distinct peaks in a segment.

If the data shown are the full extent of each signal than putting the data in windows or 'epochs' may not be necessary. Longer signals would ordinarily be examined using a static or sliding window.